# Testing VueJS application visual side

Tags: css, vue.js, testing, regression

1. How to test styles in VueJS application? I don't want to check if some container has the particular attribute but I want to check if it looks good, visually. For example, when I add somewhere "position: relative" it can broke code in a lot of places. It may cause problems with for example absolutely positioned popovers, dialogs etc. It is impossible to write a code to detect similar cases, it should be tested "vusually". Maybe something what would take screenshots and compare them? I have a lot of regression because of it. So, how should I test it?
2. How to calculate code coverage of my JEST unit tests, E2E tests and tests from pt 1*? Is any tool for this?

Comment: You're after visual regression testing, there are tools, search for them. It's independent from unit and e2e tests and doesn't affect their coverage.

Comment: Nice answer. "<OP asks for tools>" "Find tools"

Comment: That's correct. Asking for tools is off-topic on SO, exactly because this can usually be solved with a tiny bit of research. *visual regression testing* is the term, so you know what you need to search for. You can find all available tools with a single GH search query. And you're welcome.